# Go back through an Array

Tags: pseudocode

I'm currently writing my Pseudocode for an assignment for my class, and what I'm wondering is how would I go back through an array?

For a better idea of what I'm looking for, the purpose of the program is to add and subtracts days/months/years from a date from user input.

Edit: Examples upon request. We'll go from today's date.

```
cout << "Today's Date is August 23, 2013."
     << "Add Year: "
cin >> year
cout << "Add Month: "
cin >> month
cout << "Add Day: "
cin >> day
```

Now it would take the user input, and manipulate it, so let's say they input the following:
Add Year: 5
Add Month: -9
Day: 2

It would need to come out as the following

```
cout << "The modified date is: January 25, 2014"
```

It's 2014 because they subtracted enough months to go back a year, but because they added 2 years they would then only go up the one year.

Comment: some example code please (what you already tried), and some more clear description of what you're trying to achieve (example input, expected output). Also, your question title doesn't seem to reflect at all the actual problem (subtracting dates).

Comment: I'd do something like `mount = (month + (12 + n)) % 12` to change by n (-12 < n < 12) months.

Comment: [Modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes This wouldn't work if `n` is above 12.

Comment: What's the relation between your date and your array ?

Comment: What you need is `Boost.Date_Time`

Answer (score 0):

That is not "resetting" (which would likely be the same as setting the month to the first one in the array, i.e. the one at index 0), that's rather "wrapping".

You can do it with a simple if:

```
const char *monthNames[] = { "Jan", "Feb", ..., "Nov", "Dec" };
int month = 0;

--month;
if(month < 0)
  month += sizeof monthNames / sizeof *monthNames;
```

This works by first decreasing (you could have `month -= 2` to go back more), then checking if the value *underflowed*, i.e. became negative. If it did, the number of elements in the array (12) is added, which will make it right since e.g. -1 + 12 = 11 (December).

Note: The `...` in the `monthNames` initializer should be the rest of the months.

Comment: Sorry, I really should have been clearer in my code. The program needs to work off of user input. But with what you've said here the only real difference is that I would take out `--month` right? The rest of it looks like what I need to me.

I would need to do the same for days, for when they exceed 28/2930/31 or if they go below 1, this method works with that as well right?